# Why isn't this foreach loop, looping?

Tags: php, foreach

This foreach loop is supposed to loop 12 times, but is only looping 4. How come? What am I doing wrong? I am trying to put product images into a sliding carosel. The first 4 images appear no problem, but the other 8 won't appear at all.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>In the Spotlight</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">


                    <?php 
                    foreach ($products as $key => $product) { ?>

                    <div class="item <?php echo ($key == 0?"active":"");?>">

                    <?php if ($key == 0) 
                    {
                        echo "<div class=\"row\">";
                    }
                    elseif ($key == 4) 
                    {
                        echo "<div class=\"row\">";
                    }
                    elseif ($key == 8) 
                    {
                        echo "<div class=\"row\">";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a></div>
                    <?php } ?>


                    <?php if ($key == 3) 
                    {
                        echo "</div></div>";
                    }
                    elseif ($key == 7) 
                    {
                        echo "</div></div>";
                    }
                    elseif ($key == 11) 
                    {
                        echo "</div></div>";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    ?>


                  <?php } ?>



</div>
</div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**SOURCE OUTPUT**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>In the Spotlight</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">



                    <div class="item active">

                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=43"><img src="http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/macbook_1-250x250.jpg" alt="MacBook" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a></div>





                    <div class="item ">


                                        <div class="col-md-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=40"><img src="http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/iphone_1-250x250.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a></div>





                    <div class="item ">


                                        <div class="col-md-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=42"><img src="http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/w1-250x250.jpg" alt="Apple Cinema 30&quot;" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a></div>





                    <div class="item ">


                                        <div class="col-md-3"><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=49"><img src="http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/samsung_tab_1-250x250.jpg" alt="Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a></div>


                    </div></div>                    




</div>
</div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**print_r($products) shows:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 43 [thumb] => http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/macbook_1-250x250.jpg [name] => MacBook [price] => £500.00 [special] => [rating] => 0 [reviews] => Based on 0 reviews. [href] => http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=43 ) [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 40 [thumb] => http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/iphone_1-250x250.jpg [name] => iPhone [price] => £101.00 [special] => [rating] => 0 [reviews] => Based on 0 reviews. [href] => http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=40 ) [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 42 [thumb] => http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/w1-250x250.jpg [name] => Apple Cinema 30" [price] => £100.00 [special] => £90.00 [rating] => 0 [reviews] => Based on 0 reviews. [href] => http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=42 ) [3] => Array ( [product_id] => 49 [thumb] => http://localhost/theme/image/cache/data/demo/samsung_tab_1-250x250.jpg [name] => Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 [price] => £199.99 [special] => [rating] => 0 [reviews] => Based on 0 reviews. [href] => http://localhost/theme/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=49 ) )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `print_r($products)` show?

Comment: @JohnConde it shows a thumb nail of the product's image

Comment: **Show the result here**. We can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: Why are you using that `$flag` variable? Isn't the `$key` variable numeric already?

Comment: yet you are not showing output of print_r($products)

Comment: What about the cases when $flag has the value of {1,2, and 5}, if $flag goes into one of those values then the execution flows to the "else" statement which is clearly does NOT print a '<div class=\"row\">'

I think that the foreach is actually looping but you cannot see the output in your browser's view due to the lack of what i have mentioned above, try to view page source to see what i am claimng.

One more thing, you could have wrote the above code in a much better way than what you are showing here :)

Comment: culprit may be $flag ... check him

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash Can you please suggest improvements?

Comment: The source output actually shows that it's not the `$flag`, there are no signs of a crippled DOM.

Comment: Removed flag variable as it was a valid point. However, no change in output. Could this have something to do with an empty else statement? Sorry, I am relatively new to php and foreach loops.

Comment: So it looks like it only iterates 4 times becuase your array contain only 4 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `foreach` always loops through the array, so: your array has 4 items, that's why `foreach` makes 4 iterations. A `foreach` in this case is analogous to:

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($your_array); $i < $c; $i++)
```

That said, you shouldn't expect from a `foreach` to iterate more times than there are items in your array.

Comment: This was correct, there were only 4 items in the array. Thanks for your help.